# VB.NET and Access Database

Tags: vb.net

[image: Database tables]

I am trying to insert data into all those three tables at the same time. I have a database class that I call. my code goes like:

```vb
'Add Parameters
DBAccess.AddParam("@clientID", txtID.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@firstName", txtName.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@lastName", txtLastName.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@cell", txtCell.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@homeTel", txtHomeTel.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@workTel", txtWorkTel.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@email", txtEmail.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@homeAddress", txtHomeAddress.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@postalAddress", txtPostalAddress.Text)
DBAccess.AddParam("@code", txtCode.Text)

'Execute Insert Command
DBAccess.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO CLIENT ([Client_ID], [First_Name], [Last_Name]) " 
                   & VALUES (@clientID, @firstName, @lastName); ")

DBAccess.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO CONTACTS (Client_ID.C_TEL_H, Client_ID.C_TEL_W, Client_ID.C_Cell, Client_ID.C_Email) " &
          "VALUES (@homeTel, @workTel, @cell, @email, SELECT @clientID FROM CLIENT); ")
'DBAccess.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO ADDRESS ([Client_ID], [Residential_A], [Postal_A], [P_Code]) " &
' "VALUES (@clientID, @homeAddress, @postalAddress, @code);
```

Database Class

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class DatabaseControl
  'Database connection
  Private DBConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                                "Data Source=C:\Users\lance\Documents\BophelongCare.accdb;")
  'Prepare DB Command
  Private DBCommand As OleDbCommand
  'DB Data
  Public DBDAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
  Public DBDTable As DataTable

  'Query Parameters
  Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

  'Query Statistics
  Public RecordCount As Integer
  Public Exception As String

  Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
    'Rest query Statistics
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""

    Try
      'Open Connection
      DBConnection.Open()

      'Create DB Command
      DBCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBConnection)

      'Load Parameters Into DB Command
      Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCommand.Parameters.Add(p))

      'Clear Parameter List
      Params.Clear()

      'Execute Command & Fill DataTable
      DBDTable = New DataTable
      DBDAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand)
      RecordCount = DBDAdapter.Fill(DBDTable)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    'Close Connection
    If DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBConnection.Close()
  End Sub

  ' Include query & Command Parameters
  Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Please assist

Comment: What's the question?  Any errors?  Why are you filling a DataTable?  For insert, you probably should prefer an ExecuteNonQuery call.  You should probably ditch the data "helper" class.  It's not helping.

Comment: Are your Primary Keys auto-number? If so, you do not provide a value for the PK in an Insert. It seems the three Tables you have circled all relate directly to the PK of the Client table. Why 3 tables? These are one to one relationships. There are reasons to split up tables in giant database with heavy traffic but you wouldn't be using Access for that. Combine the 3 tables and write on Insert or you will need to write many Join queries.

Comment: Access requires that you add Parameters in the same order as they appear in the query. Access matches the position of the parameter, not the name.

Comment: If you insist on keeping the database as is you need to fix your sql for getting the recently inserted PK. Access can only process one query at a time. Use a new command immediately following the first Insert. `.CommandText = "Select @@IDENTITY"}`

           `Dim itgID As Integer = CInt(cmd1.ExecuteScalar)`